# Enforce schema on GraphiQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby, graphiql

How do I enforce a GraphiQL schema, but null out fields that do no exist

To provide context I have this Typescript interface

```
interface Features {
  enabled: boolean;
  limits?: Record<string, number>;
  capabilities?: string;
}
```

Within Gatsby I am trying to query an API, but with Gatsby's type inference it does not pick up on the limits and capabilities fields since they're possibly undefined.

I'm trying to utilize **createSchemaCustomization** to enforce the fields.

The closest I've gotten is

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  const typedefs = `
    interface Limits {
      days: Int
    }

    interface Feature {
      enabled: Boolean
      limits: Limits
      capabilities: String
    }

    type Performance implements TierFeature

  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

but errors are thrown since I declare them as interfaces so from my understanding I'm telling Gatsby these fields will exist.